# Unable to upload photo using my servername adress

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i'm trying to upload files using angularJs and PHP, the problem is when i try with the servername i got a problem of ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED failed to load the php file, but with adresse ip evrything works fine, any suggestion ? Thank you.
here is the message error :

```
Failed to load resource:/php/ws_upload_file net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
15:01:00.628 controllers.js:1640 null
15:01:00.656 ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property 'state_code' of null
    at controllers.js:1641
    at services.js:349
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24829)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25027)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestError (ionic.bundle.js:24978)
(anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:26799
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the php function gethostbyname ($hostname) to get the ip address of the server first then use the ip address from this function call to upload your files. Everything should be fine then!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php